# Selenium WebDriver + Cucumber - methods returning page objects

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I'm using Selenium WebDriver + Cucumber. Last time I was advised to start creating methods returning page objects instead of just void methods. The main advantage that was mentioned was that thanks to it it's not necessary to initialise all the page objects at the beginning of test class as it can be done within the test method.

I've been thinking about it for a while and I think it's a great idea when we don't use BDD tests and whole test scenario is contained in the body of one test method. But, in case we use Cucumber, the problem is that scenario is built of test steps being separate methods and page objects initialised in one step are not available in another. It forces us to initialise one page in many steps which does not match the advantage I mentioned in the previous paragraph.

Let's say we have the following situation:

```
public class Page1 {
  public Page2 method1 {
    [...]
    return new Page2(driver);
  }
}

public class Page2 {
  public Page2 method2 {
    [...]
    return this;
  }
}

public class TestClass {
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

  @Given("Step 1")
  public void step1() {
    Page1 p1 = new Page1(driver);
    [...]
    Page2 p2 = p1.method1;
  }

  @When("Step 2")
  public void step2() {
    p2.method2(); // Here I have a problem, as p2 is not initialised.
  }
}
```

Could you please advice if there is some great way to use methods returning page objects along with the BDD tests created using Cucumber? Thanks!

Comment: If you choose to initialize page objects in that fashion, you simply need to declare the page objects at the class level, and make sure the steps are executed in the sequence you expect them to be.  In the case of BDD, that last part isn't really an issue, but worth noting.

Comment: Better option would be to look at a DI container to manage the object creation. cucumber implementation of picocontainer does it seamlessly using constructor injection. https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/java-di  http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer